# SQL - SELECT all records for month based on timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an SQL query that selects all records within a 24 hour period, however, I need to update it to select all the records within a month (relative to a records timestamp). So for example if I selected any record within the month of Feb, it should return all records from the beginning to the end of the month.

The code I have to the daily query is:

```
SELECT  Snapshot.xId,  MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp) AS Timestamp_Actual, 
                dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp)), 0) AS TimestampRange_Start,
                dateadd(MI, 1439, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp)), 0)) AS TimestampRange_End
                FROM Snapshot
                GROUP BY Snapshot.xId
```

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT  Snapshot.xId,  MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp) AS Timestamp_Actual, 
                dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp)), 0) AS TimestampRange_Start,
                dateadd(dd, 0, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp)), 0)) AS TimestampRange_End
                FROM Snapshot
                GROUP BY Snapshot.xId
```

From the above statement, I can then include a standard WHERE clause to check the values of TimestampRange_Start and TimestampRange_End to see if Timestamp_Actual falls between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Snapshot.xId, MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp) AS Timestamp_Actual
  FROM Snapshot
 GROUP BY Snapshot.xId
HAVING MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp) >= dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0)
   AND MAX(Snapshot.TimeStamp) <  dateadd(mm, 1+datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Richard; I modified it a little to the following to my requirements: 'SELECT BMS_Snapshot.BuildingId,  MAX(BMS_Snapshot.TimeStamp) AS Timestamp_Actual,
    dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, MAX(BMS_Snapshot.TimeStamp)), 0) AS TimestampRange_Start,
    dateadd(mm, 1+datediff(mm, 0, MAX(BMS_Snapshot.TimeStamp)), 0) AS TimestampRange_End
    FROM BMS_Snapshot
    GROUP BY BMS_Snapshot.BuildingId'